# `model` property seems to do nothing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I forked a fiddle with a simple radio button functionality and changed it a bit. It works perfectly, as you can see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hdodov/yqgr4wb5/):

```js
Vue.component('radio-button', {
    props: ['id', 'value'],
    template: `
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" :value="id" v-model="radioButtonValue">
        <span>{{ id }}</span>
    </label>
    `,
    computed: {
        radioButtonValue: {
            get: function() {
                return this.value;
            },
            set: function() {
                this.$emit("input", this.id);
            }
        }
    }
});

Vue.component('example-form', {
    template: `
        <div>
            <radio-button id="1" v-model="selectedValue"/>
            <radio-button id="2" v-model="selectedValue"/>
            <radio-button id="3" v-model="selectedValue"/>
            <div class="result">
                Radio button selection: {{selectedValue}}
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
    data: function() {
        return {
            selectedValue: null
        };
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#my-app',
    template: `<example-form></example-form>`
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.4/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="my-app"></div>
```

However, it only seems to work when the emitted event in the radio-button component is `input`.

If, for example, I want to use a different value name ("myvar") and a custom event name ("foobar") by utilizing the [`model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model) property to do so, it doesn't work at all:

```js
Vue.component('radio-button', {
    props: ['id', 'myval'],
    model: {
        prop: 'myval',
        event: 'foobar'
    },
    template: `
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" :value="id" v-model="radioButtonValue">
        <span>{{ id }}</span>
    </label>
    `,
    computed: {
        radioButtonValue: {
            get: function() {
                return this.myval;
            },
            set: function() {
                this.$emit("foobar", this.id);
            }
        }
    }
});

Vue.component('example-form', {
    template: `
        <div>
            <radio-button id="1" v-model="selectedValue"/>
            <radio-button id="2" v-model="selectedValue"/>
            <radio-button id="3" v-model="selectedValue"/>
            <div class="result">
                Radio button selection: {{selectedValue}}
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
    data: function() {
        return {
            selectedValue: null
        };
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#my-app',
    template: `<example-form></example-form>`
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.4/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="my-app"></div>
```

What the `model` property does is it specifies that:

```
<radio-button id="1" v-model="selectedValue"/>
```

is "translated" to:

```
<radio-button id="1" :myvar="selectedValue" @foobar="selectedValue = $event"/>
```

instead of the default:

```
<radio-button id="1" :value="selectedValue" @input="selectedValue = $event"/>
```

is that right?

---

Am I missing something or is this a bug in Vue?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is how v-model works

`v-model="anything"` is shorthand for `:value="anything" @input="anything = $event"`.  So unless you follow that convention of accepting a value prop and emiting an input event, your parent component will not work.

The reason that your first example works is because your radio button component accepts a value prop and you emit an input

So in this case you have two options, follow the convention of v-model in your radio-button component or do something custom and pass down any prop name and emit any event up.